# Can't invoke method from initscript

Tags: gradle, groovy

If I change my `~/.gradle/init.gradle` to the following:

```
def hi() {
    println "hello"
}

hi()

initscript {
}
```

Then running a gradle build outputs:

```
hello
> Task :prepareKotlinBuildScriptModel UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 366ms
```

But if I change `~/.gradle/init.gradle` to *this*:

```
def hi() {
    println "hello"
}

initscript {
    hi()
}
```

Then the gradle build outputs:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Initialization script '~/.gradle/init.gradle' line: 6

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating initialization script.
> Could not find method hi() for arguments [] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.initialization.DefaultScriptHandler.
```

Why is this?

And how can I invoke `hi()` from within the initscript block?

Answer (score 0):

see link below to understand the `initscript` closure better - in short you can not do actions inside; you can only configure - see diff example of linking actions to tasks https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/init_scripts.html#sec:writing_an_init_script

Comment: Isn't configuring considered "an action", though? For example when writing `initscript { repositories{.....}}` then `repositories` is a method call under the hood

Answer (score 0):

Credit to ephemient from the Gradle community-support slack channel:

> `buildscript`, `initscript`, `plugins`, and `pluginManagement` are all
> special blocks that extracted and run separately, before any other
> part of the script. this is necessary because Gradle needs to use them
> to set up the build environment for the rest of the script. you cannot
> use anything defined outside of the block, in these blocks.

Another note: if I change `init.gradle` to

```
initscript {
    def hi() {
        println "hello"
    }
    hi()
}
```

then the following error is output:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Initialization script '~/.gradle/init.gradle' line: 2

* What went wrong:
Could not compile initialization script '/Users/aloneitan/.gradle/init.gradle'.
> startup failed:
  initialization script '~/.gradle/init.gradle': 2: Method definition not expected here. Please define the method at an appropriate place or perhaps try using a block/Closure instead. at line: 2 column: 5. File: _BuildScript_ @ line 2, column 5.
         def hi() {
         ^
  
  1 error
```

It appears that the answer is that **it is not possible to define a method to be used inside `initscript` using Groovy**

It is worth noting that it *is* possible in Kotlin, though.